# Modify .bst to introduce a comma instead of a period after article name

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, bst

I am preparing the bibliography for a journal and I am trying to follow its formatting guidelines. I have already made a few changes to the "apalike.bst" file, thanks to several answers posted to this forum, but I wasn't able to replace the period after an article name with a comma, as requested by the journal. In other words, my references currently look like this:

> La Porta, R., de Silanes, F. L., Shleifer, A., and Vishny, R. W.
> (1997) Legal determinants of external finance. *Journal of Finance*
> 52(3), 1131–1150.

but I need:

> La Porta, R., de Silanes, F. L., Shleifer, A., and Vishny, R. W.
> (1997) Legal determinants of external finance, *Journal of Finance*
> 52(3), 1131–1150.

Any tips would be super-helpful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you, Mensch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need this for the `article` type, then you can simply comment out the `new.block` that appears after the `format.title` call in the `article` function:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output                              % special for
  output.year.check                                     % apalike
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
% new.block % <---- commented this line
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

If you need the same format for other titles, you may need to comment out `new.block` in other places.

Comment: Thank you so much, Alan, this is perfect!